# Netsuite Suitelet SSv1 Change Multiselect Value to Array

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a multiselect field in the GET section of my suitelet and I am trying to use the value of this field in the POST section.

Here is my multiselect field in the GET section as it is populated by an Object:

```
var marketplacesList = form.addField('selectedmarketplaces','multiselect','Marketplaces',null,'part3');

    for (var k in marketplaces){

        marketplacesList.addSelectOption(k,marketplaces[k].label);

    }
```

Then when I log the value in the POST section as such:

```
    var selectedMarkets = request.getParameter('selectedmarketplaces'); //gets a multiselect from GET section

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','selectedMarkets',selectedMarkets);
```

I get the following string:

"amazonComamazonUKamazonCAamazonFRamazonDEamazonITamazonJPamazonESebayComebayUkebayAuebayVolt"

How do I make the value of the multiselect an array so I can use it for iteration, etc.?

Thanks,

- Jesse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var selectedMarkets = request.getParameter('selectedmarketplaces'); //gets a multiselect from GET section
selectedMarketsArray   = selectedMarkets.split("\u0005"); //Turns it into an array
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','selectedMarketsArray',JSON.stringify(selectedMarketsArray));
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Would you explain how split("\u0005") works?

Comment: The values are separated by the ENQUIRY unicode character which is prob not visible when you do a log execution. More info here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0005/index.htm

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.

Comment: Awesome!  I was about to post in the user group about this.

Answer (score 1):

For Netsuite 2.0

```
var perams = context.request.parameters.selectedmarketplaces.split("\u0005") //Turns it into an array
log.debug('perms', perams)
```